# storing date range in PostgreSQL/PostGIS for time parameter in WMS/WFS

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql, time, wms-time

Using GeoServer I want to deliver some objects/features with WFS and WMS. The objects and their attributes have a date range during which they are valid. Say, we have street lamps and each street lamp has an `ID`, `POINT (geom)`, `start_date`, `end_date`.

The WMS and WFS request can use the `time` parameter to filter the resulting objects (see [WFS GetFeature with time](http://www.ogcnetwork.net/node/178), [WMS GetMap with time](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/time.html)). Using the time filter, only the street lamps that a within `start_date` and `end_date` would be returned by GeoServer .

However, I now saw that for `time` the respective time column must be stored with a `date` type. That is, in geoserver one cannot configure start or end date columns for a WMS or WFS layer. It is only possible to configure a single date column (same for MapServer).

What's the best way to store my street lamps in PostgreSQL/PostGIS? For a lamp that was created on Jan 01, 2014 and destroyed on Jan 20, 2014 would I need to have 20 data sets in my database:

```
ID GEOM DATE
01 xy   2014-01-01
01 xy   2014-01-02
...
01 xy   2014-01-19
01 xy   2014-01-20
```

Is there a way to store date ranges in PostgreSQL/PostGIS that can be used by GeoServer? Or is this impossible?

Comment: Wow, that's ridiculous - surely there must be a way to specify a range. Ideally for this you'd use PostgreSQL's `tsrange` data type, but just a pair of timestamps would be quite sufficient in a pinch.

Comment: It's possible that this isn't yet supported - feel free to contribute code that does implement it. - It is unlikely to be possible to use a `tsrange` as GeoServer (and GeoTools) have to function over a lot of datastores

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In GeoServer you *can* specify a start and an end date column, see the documentation at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/webadmin/data/layers.html#edit-dimensions.

All you need is two date columns i.e. two columns with `date` datatype in your database.